# ng serve Project target does not exist

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Since upgrading my app from Angular 10 -> 14, I am unable to `ng serve` my application. Running `ng build` runs successfully.

Running the following results in the following error:

`ng serve` -> *Cannot determine project or target for command.*

`ng serve applicationNamee` -> *Error: Invalid values:
Argument: project, Given: "applicationNamee", Choices: "applicationName"*

`ng serve applicationName` -> *Project target does not exist.*

File structure is as follows

```
angular.json
package.json
e2e
dist
node_modules
-- src
-- src/app
```

I've ensured that the name property in `package.json` matches the project name in `angular.json`

Comment: You must add your project folder structure and command prompt screen shoot in your question for answering that question.

Comment: I got the same error when trying to run a different command on my project (ng extract-i18n) because there was a formatting error in angular.json. I forgot to put a comma after a section and a closing curly brace. Also (in case someone finds this answer from searching on "Unknown argument: output-path"), when I tried to put an "--output-path" into my command, I got the error "Unknown argument: output-path".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across this who is migrating from an existing angular app, ensure that the properties within `angular.json` are as below

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "portfolio-viewer-v2": {
     "root": "",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "projectType": "application",
    "prefix": "app",
    "schematics": {},
    "architect": {
      "build": {},
      "serve": {},
      "e2e" : {},
      "test": {},
      "lint": {},
      "extract-i18n": {},
      "server": {},
      "app-shell": {}
        }
    }
  }
}
```